# Compare texts in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to compare texts in Apps script? I need to know if the value stored in the variable cellColumnaB contains the text "Jornada", but I don't know if there is a function that does it or if it has to be built.

```
function myFunction() {
    var objetoLibro = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dv4FWDjhCJrruzDZsEyPPjUBHjUI-FJ9RhG68nL07qI");//abre el libro
    var objetoHoja = objetoLibro.getSheets()[0];//obtiene la hoja 1
    var dblUltimaFila = objetoHoja.getLastRow();//obtiene el numero de filas

    for (var i = 1; i < dblUltimaFila; i++) {
        var cellColumnaB = objetoHoja.getRange(i, 2).getValues();//obtiene los valores de la columna 2
  
        if( cellColumnaB.includes("Jornada") ){
            Logger.log(cellColumnaB);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description**

In your OP `objetoHoja.getRange(i, 2).getValues()`.  getValues() returns a 2D array, not a single value.  So include will not find the string "Jornada".

Might I suggest the following modifications to your script.  Get all the values from `objetoHoja` and then loop through the 2D array to compare strings.

**Code.gs**

```
function myFunction() {
    var objetoLibro = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dv4FWDjhCJrruzDZsEyPPjUBHjUI-FJ9RhG68nL07qI");//abre el libro
    var objetoHoja = objetoLibro.getSheets()[0];//obtiene la hoja 1
    var dblUltimaFila = objetoHoja.getDataRange().getValues();

    for (var i = 1; i < dblUltimaFila.length; i++) {
        var cellColumnaB = dblUltimaFila[i][1];
  
        if( cellColumnaB.includes("Jornada") ){
            Logger.log(cellColumnaB);
        }
    }
}
```